# C++ LoadLibrary Returns Null

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to load a simple DLL named "MathLib.dll" for testing. The path to the DLL is `D:\Desktop\MathLib\MathLib.dll`. In this code, dll is always null and "Failed to load" is printed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary(L"D:\Desktop\MathLib\MathLib.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Loaded!";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is with the path, but I don't know what I could do differently.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in string literals `D:\\Desktop\\MathLib\\MathLib.dll`, or use raw string literals

Comment: On Window's it's best to replace the back slashes with forward slashes when dealing with paths. That way it automatically escapes spaces as well and the string will be more legible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Praetorian's comment and Mike's answer about doubling the backslashes,  you must also make sure that the dll you load is compatible with your code (i.e. if you compile in x64 the library must be x64).

I suggest you use [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The [error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will tell you where to look.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought ... and it well may be wrong ... is that you should *double* those backslashes in your string-constant, so that they will be interpreted as "literally, a backslash," not an escape-sequence like "\n."

My instinct is that *LoadLibrary* is not receiving the string that you think it is!